# What's the difference between a fingerprint and a hash?

Tags: functions, computer-science, hash-function

My understanding is that both a fingerprint and a hash are functions that take as input some arbitrarily long bitstring, and output a bitstring of a fixed size.  The [Wikipedia page for Hash Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) says:

> Hash functions are related to (and often confused with) ... fingerprints

But try as I may, I can't find any sources that mention the difference between the two.  Do you know what the difference between a hash function and a fingerprinting function  is?

Comment: Fingerprint or digest is the **result** of a hash fucntion,  not the function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'm asking about the difference between hashing functions and fingerprinting functions.  Or alternatively, the difference between a hash and a fingerprint.  The wikipedia page implies that there is a difference between the two, though you're right in that it uses the wrong terminology (it should say hash functions are related to fingerprinting functions).

Comment: When comparing both descriptions I see a difference in the length of the result, for hash functions **it is fixed** but there is no such restriction of fingerprinting functions.
But I am no expert, if you need a definite answer you may ask at https://crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: A hash function is something which assign a shorter bit string for each item in a large pool of items. For practical purposes, the hash values for different items should seldom to collide but there is no guarantee they won't collide at all. A fingerprint is supposed to be something  that **uniquely identifies** the original item for all practical purposes.

Comment: @gammatester A "hash" is the result of a hash function, too.

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that cryptographic hash functions need to be resistant to reversing. I.e. One should not be able to calculate possible messages from a hash value. If this were not the case, hashing passwords wouldn't be (as) secure.

Fingerprint functions, on the other hand, are fine even if you can calculate possible messages from a fingerprint. They just need to identify a file/object.

Comment: I'd agree this is the difference between "cryptographic hash functions" (like you said) and fingerprints, but I think it's just as true to say it's the difference between "cryptographic hash functions" and "hash functions", so I think this answers a slightly different question than the one I asked. Thanks nonetheless for the input!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, it looks like the difference is the same as the difference between $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $P \iff Q$. Strictly speaking if $h$ is a hash function then it must be a fingerprinting function however the converse is not true, i. e., if $h$ is a fingerprinting function then we don't know if it is a hash function or not.

Notice that here by a hash function we mean what is colloquially referred to as a *cryptographic* hash function. If the context differentiates between a *cryptographic* hash function and *just* a hash function, that function may be a fingerprinting function and not a hash function. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_(computing)#Cryptographic_hash_functions): *Fingerprint (computing)* says:

> Mainstream cryptographic grade hash functions generally can serve as high-quality fingerprint functions, are subject to intense scrutiny from cryptanalysts, and have the advantage that they are believed to be safe against malicious attacks.

Therefore it feels like a set of all hash functions $\mathcal{H}$ is a **smaller** subset of the set of all fingerprinting functions $\mathcal{F}$. Therefore, we may write:

$$
f \in \mathcal{H} \Rightarrow f \in \mathcal{F}
$$